# What to do after missing the registration deadline for the GRE subject test in mathematics

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, mathematics, gre

Having missed the registration deadline for the GRE math subject test, I've been looking into the option of working for a year and then applying to math PhD programs once I have my test results. While I could try applying to the top programs I'm interested in this year, they generally say that my application will either be at a disadvantage or it will be disregarded entirely without a subject test score.

Since there are some (less competitive) US graduate programs that don't require the GRE, I was wondering if it would be a bad idea to attend one of them for a year and then try to transfer out? I thought it'd be a cost-effective way to take more math classes, but I read in [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/2502/24280) that:

> It's difficult to transfer to a substantially more prestigious department. [...] No matter why you say you want to transfer, there will be some suspicion that your goal is to end up in a stronger department or a more desirable location. If you have another reason, you'll have to make a powerful argument for it.

So, I'm trying to figure out which idea is better: apply to a second-tier PhD program with the intent of transferring to a first-tier program, or find a job and just apply to schools after I take the subject test?

(Note: I recently asked [a more general question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/56063/ways-to-spend-gap-year-semester-before-applying-to-mathematics-phd) about my options if I choose to take a gap year.)

Comment: You can try to take the October test on standby.  There is information on how to do this on [the ets website](https://www.ets.org/gre/subject/register/arrangements/).

Comment: @Rori Thank you! I did not know about that! I just called ETS and they told me to call again the Monday before the test, and they'll tell me which centers will be offering standby testing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although not a direct answer to the question, there is a third option:

**Take the October test on standby**

From the [ETS website](https://www.ets.org/gre/subject/register/arrangements/):

> Standby testing may be available if sufficient space, test materials
>   and staff are available at the test center. If you'd like to attempt
>   to test as a standby, report to the test center by 8:15 a.m. with:
>
> a completed Registration Form for the GRE Subject Tests (PDF) payment
>   (including the registration and standby testing fee) acceptable photo
>   ID Standby registration is not available for Monday testing, testing
>   in Mainland China, Hong Kong, Taiwan, Korea, India, or Iran, or those
>   requesting disability or health-related testing accommodations.

I don't know how many standby seats are generally available, but it seems worth a shot rather than delaying your studies by a year.

Comment: For others reading this - after speaking with ETS, they advised me that standby test-takers should call ETS the Monday before the test date and check which centers will be available for standby testing, since not all centers may offer it.

Comment: @justin - Go for it!  //  If that doesn't work out, please apply for a master's program rather than a doctoral degree program.